How to create SCP for block public s3 bucket with exception to resource tags?
I am trying to create SCP that blocks public C3 buckets which I find the solution using:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock",
        "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
    }
  ]
}

However, I am unable to find solution where I can allow certain buckets to be public if they have Bucket Tag: key1:value1

Check out conditions that are supported for S3 API calls. You can use the aws:RequestTag condition in the SCP.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-policy-keys
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-requesttag
